# MySQL highscore ranking for a specific user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve a specific users rank from my `hs_users` table which has `id`, `username` and `score` columns.

I currently have the query to retrieve the results by ranking users like this:

```
|         Results         |
|-------------------------|
| username | score | rank |
|----------+-------+------|
| Ozan     | 10000 |    1 |
| Potato   |  8000 |    2 |
| Carrot   |  8000 |    2 |
| Tomato   |  5000 |    4 |
```

So the user **tomato** is in rank **4**.

I tried many combinations from all over stackoverflow to retrieve a single results with its ranking, but could only manage to retrieve this result by using a `WHERE` clause.

```
|         Results         |
|-------------------------|
| username | score | rank |
|----------+-------+------|
| Tomato   |  5000 |    1 |
```

The rank of **tomato** should have been **4** instead of **1**.

Please explain the query you send as an answer if you do. :D

The point is to learn how it works.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Better edit the question to include the query that creates the ranks.

Comment: Which query you have tried?

Comment: What and how exactly are you trying to retrieve the results?
Are you trying to apply condition on username or ranks or both?

Comment: how Tomato  got 4 th rank, he should get 3 right?

Comment: @SagarPanda I am trying to get the user __tomato__ with the rank "4" as a result. (Retrieve a single user from whole table while ranking it.)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr They are useless...

Comment: @FathahRehmanP No, there are 3 people in front of him...

Comment: @OzanKurt - no Rank 3??

Comment: @OzanKurt no, the query is not useless - it is needed because a slight modification is likely to get to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The below query fill fetch you the results where username is Tomato and rank is 4.

> SELECT * from hs_users where username= 'Tomato' and rank=4;

If there are multiple user's with name as 'Tomato' and if you want all those users irrespective of their ranks, then use:

> SELECT * from hs_users where username= 'Tomato';

Comment: Can you post your query here?
You can also use the above query, instead of Results use your table name.